# Is data URI in <img> tag not supported?

Tags: support, images

I'm trying to include inline SVG images into a post but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Tried it out in the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354954/419414), and it looks like data URI doesn't work with PNG either.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,[Base64-encoded data]" />
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,[URI-encoded data]" />
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,[Base64-encoded data]" />
```

I think I saw some post before saying that embedding SVG works by writing `<img>` tag manually, but it's probably not about using the data URI. Also I can't find any documentation that says data URIs are allowed/banned/filtered out/whatever. I need it to work around the corporate firewall blocking all file uploads (including all types of images, and even putting the data URI into the image upload dialog doesn't work).

Comment: Based on the fact that [`href` attributes for links don't support any protocols other than HTTP and HTTPS](/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), I think the same is true for image sources as well.

Comment: TIL [data URI *can* be used in malicious ways](https://www.paladion.net/blogs/bypass-xss-filters-using-data-uris). Now it makes sense to block data URIs in image source. :/

Answer (score 10):

This workaround is successful:

```html
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
```

To display the image hit the [Run Code Snippet] button.

---

Now for your example image:

```html
<img width="48" height="48" alt="png_Bubbler" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

SVG image:

[image]

SVG inline image:

```html
<img width="187" height="68" alt="asteriskSVG" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 187.083 67.977'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E .a, .b, .c %7B fill: %23eda921; %7D .a, .b %7B stroke: %23000; stroke-miterlimit: 10; %7D .a %7B stroke-width: 9.122px; %7D .b %7B stroke-width: 9.122px; %7D .d %7B fill: %23005a9c; %7D %3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Ctitle%3ESVGlogo%3C/title%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath class='a' d='M13.745,30.137a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,0,7.608H54.137a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,0-7.608Z'/%3E%3Cpath class='b' d='M22.351,16.971a5.381,5.381,0,1,0-5.38,5.38L45.532,50.912a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,5.38-5.38Z'/%3E%3Cpath class='a' d='M37.745,13.745a5.38,5.38,0,1,0-7.608,0V54.137a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,7.608,0Z'/%3E%3Cpath class='b' d='M50.912,22.351a5.381,5.381,0,1,0-5.38-5.38L16.971,45.532a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,5.38,5.38Z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath class='c' d='M13.745,30.137a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,0,7.608H54.137a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,0-7.608Z'/%3E%3Cpath class='c' d='M22.351,16.971a5.381,5.381,0,1,0-5.38,5.38L45.532,50.912a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,5.38-5.38Z'/%3E%3Cpath class='c' d='M37.745,13.745a5.38,5.38,0,1,0-7.608,0V54.137a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,7.608,0Z'/%3E%3Cpath class='c' d='M50.912,22.351a5.381,5.381,0,1,0-5.38-5.38L16.971,45.532a5.38,5.38,0,1,0,5.38,5.38Z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath class='d' d='M74.062,34.166a19.8,19.8,0,1,1,33.8-14h-11.6A8.2,8.2,0,1,0,82.257,25.96h0c1.485,1.49,2.722,1.921,5.8,2.409h0c5.471.569,10.419,2.219,14,5.8h0a19.8,19.8,0,1,1-33.8,14h11.6a8.2,8.2,0,1,0,14.009-5.792h-.006c-1.485-1.485-3.615-2-5.8-2.4v-.006c-5.3-.813-10.415-2.218-14-5.8Z'/%3E%3Cpath class='d' d='M147.469.367,133.462,67.976h-11.6l-14-67.609h11.6l8.208,39.6,8.2-39.6Z'/%3E%3Cpath class='d' d='M167.276,28.369h19.8v19.8h.006a19.8,19.8,0,1,1-39.607,0h0v-28h-.006a19.8,19.8,0,0,1,39.607,0h-11.6a8.2,8.2,0,1,0-16.4,0v28h0a8.2,8.2,0,0,0,16.4,0v-8.2h-8.2V28.369Z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A" />
```

Bubbler, you can hit the "Edit" link to see the trick; which may not work on all our sites.

---

> "I need it to work around the corporate firewall blocking all file uploads (including all types of images, and even putting the data URI into the image upload dialog doesn't work).".

In case it wasn't obvious, once you've successfully transferred your image past the firewall you can right click on it and copy it (it only worked with the Chrome browser (for me), Firefox didn't work).

Now you can choose to upload an image, and paste the image; providing this result from your two examples:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the .SVG file probably doesn't produce the desired result; so stick with .jpg or .png files.